# Bad state: field does not exist within the DocumentSnapshotPlatform. Giving this error but don't know where the error is

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Hi this is my code but it gives me this error:
Bad state: field does not exist within the DocumentSnapshotPlatform.
im not sure where is the error.

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class OrderSuccessful extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _OrderSuccessfulState createState() => _OrderSuccessfulState();
}

  class _OrderSuccessfulState extends State<OrderSuccessful>{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Order Successful")),
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,

      body: StreamBuilder(
        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('personalinfo').snapshots(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot){
        if (!snapshot.hasData){
          return Text("no value");
        }
        return ListView(
          children: snapshot.data!.docs.map((document){
            return Text(document['personalinfo']);
          }).toList(),
        );
        },
        ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to access a field named `personalinfo` from the documents inside the collection in the named `personalinfo` but unfortunlly this field doesn't exist.

So make sure that **all** the documents inside the `personalinfo` collection  contains a key named `personalinfo` or just add a condition to check its existence before using it such as: `document.contains('personalinfo')`.

The line you are using to access the field is:

```
return Text(document['personalinfo']);
```

Comment: You're right I was using the wrong key for the collection, thank you for your time answering this question! :)

Comment: You're always welcome, I would be glad if you accepted the answer.